# Metamask tokens not showing

Tags: metamask

This is the situation :

I had some tokens in my Metamask and had no problems doing transactions for a while.
After that, a week or two after my last login, I tried accessing my Metamask with the seed phrases but no other wallets are displaying with the amount of tokens, yet, my transaction history shows the token transaction histories which I've sent within my Metamask account.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Have you checked on Etherscan to see if your account owns the tokens ?

Comment: MetaMask has by default predefined list with tokens, but not from long ago they're not supporting the update of that list. You have to add your token manually like a "Custom token" by inserting the contract address of token.